# Slick multiple class same function - looking for best solution

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I am using Slick as an add on for my end user from other teams to use. I want to make it as simple as possible for them to use by just changing the outside wrap as (carousel-wrap-1, carousel-wrap-2 ….etc) if they need more than one on the page. 
Questions:
1. Is that possible to make the JS function like this?? (Attached is my js code look like, Plus my fix for the equal height for all the slide.) 
OR
2. I still can ask them to copy and paste everytime they want to add a new set of  carousel, but inside the "prevArrow and nextArrow", how to make it call only that parent? (thinking something $(this) + $(".prev")) ??

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[class*='carousel-wrap-'] .carousel").slick({
prevArrow: $(".prev"),
nextArrow: $(".next"),
accessibility: true,
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 7000,
dots: true,
infinite: true,
speed: 600,
fade: true,
cssEase: 'linear',
pauseOnHover: true,
pauseOnFocus: true,
});


});

$(document).ready(function() {
  var offsetHeight = $('.slick-list').outerHeight();
  $("[class*='carousel-wrap-'] .carousel .band").outerHeight(offsetHeight);
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
  $("[class*='carousel-wrap-'] .carousel .band").css("height", "100%")
  var offsetHeight = $('.slick-list').outerHeight();
  $("[class*='carousel-wrap-'] .carousel .band").outerHeight(offsetHeight);
});
```

```html
<div class="carousel-wrap-1">
<div class="carousel-control">
      <div class="prev"></div><div class="next"></div>
      </div>
      
  <div class="carousel">
      <div class="band slide1"></div>
      <div class="band slide2"></div>
      <div class="band slide3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this, but not sure how to combine

```js
$("[class*='carousel-wrap-'] .carousel").each(function() {
  $(this).slick({
  appendArrows: $(this).siblings('.carousel-control'),
  accessibility: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 7000,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 600,
  fade: true,
  cssEase: 'linear',
  pauseOnHover: true,
  pauseOnFocus: true,
  });
  
   });
```

the equal height together.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use one function for multiple classes. you just pass in all class names you want to use that function. like this:

```
$('.celebrities, .sellers').slick({
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 6,
    slidesToScroll: 1
  }
```

It worked for me. my classes are

> celebrities
> and
> sellers